# I accidentally deleted all my photos in iPhoto on my Mac

Tags: photos.app

I did not empty the trash. How can I get these photos back?

Answer (score 5):

If you did not empty the trash, then they will still be in iPhoto's trash. Select the photos in the trash and choose Photos → Restore to iPhoto Library.